# Нужно ли тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Немцы снова в Крыму.* Нужно ли тире?

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, в каком месте у вас тире?!

Comment: та уже паранойя какая-то...)

Comment: Можно перед словом "немцы" поставить, если начать предложение подходящим образом: "Только вздремну - немцы снова в Крыму".

Comment: У Вас,  Alex_ander, удачный вариант, да ещё и в рифму.

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение не требует постановки тире.

Comment: Правда, не требует?

Comment: Если только предусмотрен некий исключительный контекст, требующий особой интонации. Тогда возможно поставить. Но и это лишнее, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Разумеется, тире не ставится.